# How do i find indexOfObject in an array that has dictionaries

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

Here is my array :

```
<__NSCFArray 0x7b6ca390>(
{
    name = kumar;
    no = 158;
},
{
    name = rajdeep;
    no = 338;
},
{
    name = smitha;
    no = 361;
},
{
    name = uma;
    no = 422;
}
)
```

This is what I am trying to do

```
NSInteger selectedIndexpath=[self.arrLoadCell indexOfObject:_txtfield.text];
```

where

```
_txtfield.text = @"rajdeep"
```

and i get some random junk value like 2147483647 stored in selectedIndexPath.
Am i missing something? Or is there anyother way to handle it?

Comment: `<__NSCFArray 0x7b6ca390>` is this debugger output?

Comment: @SebastianDressler yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This "junk value" seems to be `NSNotFound`, which you should check against when using this method. Long story short, your array does not contain the value you are looking for. It does not work, because you are looking for a string but the array contains dictionaries, so you would have too search for e.g. `{ "name" : "rajdeep", "no" : @338 }`.

Alternatively, to make this work with strings only, use `NSPredicate` for filtering, e.g.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name ==  %@", valueFromTextbox];
NSArray result = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate: predicate];
```

If your array is very short you can also make a loop for comparison.

**Update** to get the index, use the result of the predicate as input, e.g.

```
NSInteger selectedIndexpath = [self.arrLoadCell indexOfObject:result.firstObject];
```

Comment: but in this case it does. Check the dictionary that is there in the second index it does have the string rajdeep

Comment: Sure it has, but your search method will never find this entry, see my edited answer.

Comment: thanks @Sebastian . I checked your reply and the array result has the dictionary that i was searching for, but i want the index of the dictionary in the main array. I tried `NSInteger selectedIndexpath=[self.arrLoadCell indexOfObject:result];` it still returns the same junk data

Comment: Or is it that i can compare only strings in `indexOfObject:` method? But when i checked NSArray.h file the method accepts id `- (NSUInteger)indexOfObject:(id)anObject;`

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed that and updated the answer now to include this piece of information.

Answer (score 3):

indexOfObject: requires the actual object that is stored in the array. You are providing only the value of a key for one of the Dictionaries.

One of the ways you could achieve what you want, is to loop through the array and for each dictionary, test the value.

The "junk value" you got is NSNotFound, which means that the object was not found.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your array contains Dictionaries, not Strings. You cannot compare your String (textfield.text) with the dictionaries that are in your array.

Comment: oh okay, Thanks. Yeah makes sense. So how do i proceed? I mean is there anything that i can do without looping or traversing the array?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is:

```
int idx = NSNotFound;
for (int i=0; i<self.arrLoadCell.count; i++) {
    NSDictionary *dict = [self.arrLoadCell objectAtIndex:i];
    if ([[dict objectForKey:@"name"] isEqualToString:_txtfield.text]) {
        idx = i;
        break;
    }
}
NSInteger selectedIndexpath=idx;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSUInteger indexPath = 0;
    for (NSDictionary *dic in arrLoadCell){
        if ([[dic objectForKey:@"name"] isEqualToString: _txtfield.text]) {
            indexPath=[arrLoadCell indexOfObject:dic];
            break;
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"%lu is the indexPATH",(unsigned long)indexPath);
```

Assuming that your array of dictionaries is arrLoadCell this should work.